# The punching bool is not setting the animation variable to true to false

Tags: unity-game-engine

In a nutshell, I want to code a punching script where every time the player presses a j key, the punching animation gets played. The issue is that the punching animation is not playing. Here is my code along with my screenshots with the Animator, and my animation for the punching animation.

```c#
void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.J)) // attack
    {
        print("Times they have punched");
        punching = true;
        ispunching(punching);
    } else
    {
        punching = false;
        ispunching(punching);
    }
}

void ispunching(bool punch)
{
    if(punch)
    {
        print("Punching: " + punch);
        anim.SetBool("Punch", punch);
        waittilpunchanimfinish(1f);
    }
    else if (!punch)
    {
        print("Not punching" + punch);
        anim.SetBool("Punch", punch);
    }
}

IEnumerator waittilpunchanimfinish(float time)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    punching = false;
}
```

Here is the image right here. I know the idle animation is not transitioned to the punching. I did it on purpose to simplify things so people can fix it easier :
[image: animation picture]

The Punching Animation Picture Keyframe
[image: The Punching Animation Picture Keyframe]

Comment: You should give us more informations. Did you try to check on live if your `Animator `switch the state to punch ? Did you check if the `Punch` bool on the `Animator` is set correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Update` you do

```c#
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.J)) // attack
{
    print("Times they have punched");
    punching = true;
    ispunching(punching);
} else
{
    punching = false;
    ispunching(punching);
}
```

and thereby **immediately** reset the `punching` to `false` in the next frame where `GetKeyDown` will not be `true` anymore!

---

I would instead rather do the entire punch routine inside of the Coroutine like

```c#
// The only purpose left for this flag is for not having multiple
// Corouintes at the same time.
private bool punching;

private void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

private void Update()
{
    // Only receive input if not already punching
    if(!punching && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.J)) // attack
    {
        StartCoroutine(Punch());
    }
}

// Handle the entire punch routine in one go
private IEnumerator Punch()
{
    print("Start punching");
    punching = true;
    anim.SetBool("Punch", true);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);

    anim.SetBool("Punch", false);
    punching = false;
    print("Finished punching");
}
```

Comment: If the return condition of the animation punch state specify an exit time of 1, it would complete the animation before returning to the previous state walking. Isn't it better to use this animation feature insteed of creating a coroutine ?